# How would I go about implementing share buttons automatically?

Tags: php, facebook, twitter

There are many sites that auto-generates pages with like buttons, tweet buttons, and stumbleupon buttons. My question is, how?
I'm kind of interested in the logic behind it, but if there's a code out there that makes it easy to do, I'd gladly hear it.
I do not plan for my site to be dynamic, but this automatic way of inserting share buttons can be a great lazy way to add share buttons to a page.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great service called [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com).

It also includes analytics, and works using JavaScript rather than PHP.

Search Google for tons more similar services.